# Typescript How Can I Infer Types, method like as pipe method?

Tags: typescript

```
class Pump<T> {
    constructor(public value: T){
    }
    pipe(...operators:(()=>any)[]): this{
        return operators.reduce((result, operator) => operator.call(result), this);
    }
}

function setNumber(value: number){
    return function(){
        this.value = value;
        return this as any as Pump<number>;
    };
}

function setString(value: string){
    return function(){
        this.value = value;
        return this as any as Pump<string>;
    };
}

const pump = new Pump<{}>({});

// want to infer number type
pump.pipe(setNumber(1)).value;
pump.pipe(setString('2'), setNumber(1)).value;

// want to infer string type
pump.pipe(setString('1')).value;
pump.pipe(setNUmber(2), setString('1')).value;
```

If there are not many operators, I can hard-code the results.
I already tried made for like this with 3 operators.
it's working right, but It will increase types and overloads as many as, if I add a new operator
I defined 11 overloads just for 3 operator

Not want to use generic for the pipe.
The same number of the generics with operator seems to not funny.

I want to infer the type from an operator as possible.

Operators can change T of Pump or return another constructor.
Operators can call the pipe's method if it requires it for the infer type or change type.

my explanation may not be enough to explain what I want to make.
I would be fine using anyway if it can infer the type.

Comment: I do not think you can do it for an arbitrary number of arguments / operators. Similar method is present in rxjs - this may be of interest to you: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Observable.ts#L294-L304, https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/spec-dtslint/Observable-spec.ts.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak Thanks. I already had check it. It's return `Observable` only, and should be use the generics to pipe for the infer.

Comment: There is no relation between each operator ? The way I see the functions, only the last operator decides the return type of your `pipe`, and there is no true pipeline behavior between each operator. Am I missing something ? Did something get lost along the way when you simplified the code for SO ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir
of course that's good, if can relation between each operator.
When i made the similar structure, I made every overloads of way as possible.
`pipe(1), pipe(1,2), pipe(2,1), pipe(1, 2, 3), pipe(1, 3, 2), pipe(2), pipe(2,1), pipe(2,1,3)`...
needed to define many the type and interfaces for make easy to the overload.
I want to better than it.
if pipe can figure last operator, I think operator also can infer types.

Comment: Can you add an example call where there is an interaction between operators to the question?  From what you've written, we can't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen thanks for your interest.
I decided using the override for all return types with type in the last operator only.